# How to merge two dataframes based on a similar column where condition on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge first dataframe dt1 with a second one dt2 based on a similar column col1 where a condition on a datetime column col2: What I want exactly is to take the the first dt2['Date2'] bigger than dt1['Date1']

```
dt1.head()
ID  col1    Date1
0   A   2019-12-01
1   B   2019-12-01
2   A   2019-12-02
3   C   2019-12-02
4   C   2019-12-02
5   B   2019-12-03
6   A   2019-12-03
7   A   2019-12-03

dt2.head()
ID  col1    Date2
0   A   2019-12-02
1   A   2019-12-04
2   B   2019-12-04
3   C   2019-12-03
```

The result should be like this:

```
ID  col1    Date1   Date2
0   A   01/12/2019  2019-12-02
1   B   01/12/2019  2019-12-04
2   A   02/12/2019  2019-12-04
3   C   02/12/2019  2019-12-03
4   C   02/12/2019  2019-12-03
5   B   03/12/2019  2019-12-04
6   A   03/12/2019  2019-12-04
7   A   03/12/2019  2019-12-04
```

Comment: show some sample data please

Comment: I hope these modifications can clarify my question?

Comment: https://www.shanelynn.ie/merge-join-dataframes-python-pandas-index-1/

Comment: Thank you very much I foud out how to solve this by using merge_asof